# Display single field from argument taxonomy term in Views header area

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

I have a view with a taxonomy term ID in the URL which is used to filter the displayed entities in the view.

I want to display the description from the taxonomy term.

I've tried this a million different ways.

I've even gone as far as defining a view mode for the vocabulary which only includes the field - that doesn't work because it insists on displaying the title linked to the term page (which I definitely don't want). I even tried the layout builder but that displayed the title as well.

This is not the same as modifying the page title - which I am doing successfully.

Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

I've included my original response below but it turns out I'm an idiot: All you have to do is create the taxonomy-term as a relationship and then you can just pick out the field you want. D'oh!

~~~ my original answer

Yeah, so this is a problem that is currently unsolvable without code as of Drupal 8.6.0. Unless you deploy Display Suite, which is using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

There's a lot of discussion on drupal.org about the lack of control on title fields in respect to nodes but the issue goes deeper. It applies to Taxonomy as well: You cannot stop the title field from appearing in any view mode because that's the way the template works.

The only solution is to create a new template that doesn't display the title (in my case `taxonomy-term--book-series.twig.html`) plus the supporting `hook_theme()` and `hook_preprocess_taxonomy_term__book_series()` all of which is a PITA.

Even then it's not great because there are no (default) theme suggestions for taxonomy terms that include view modes. It would have been much nicer if I could have designed a view mode called "description" and then had a theme suggestion of `taxonomy-term--description.twig.html` because that would then work in all cases. Instead I have to create the same template and support code but for a different vocabulary.

All-in-all, not the best experience.